# How to solve this StackOverflowError in this bad recursion example?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm having a programming issue related to bad recursion and StackOverflowError.
I've got this case in a separate thread:

```
public void subscribe(final String channel) {
   try {
      // blocking command
      client.subscribe(channel);
   } catch(ConnectionException e) {
      subscribe(channel);
   }
}
```

Say this ConnectionException is only happening periodically (something like every minute). After a few hundreds, I obviously obtain a StackOverflowError.

I know what's happening but I have no idea how I could solve this (i.e re-subscribing silently without increasing the calling stack). Any ideas?

Comment: what is the blocking command?

Comment: using recursion for an detecting an event is an overkill..why don't you implement and use callbacks..

Comment: The blocking command is basically a command to listen for remote data. data is pushed to a listener asynchronously in parallel.

Comment: If you wan't to implement retry mechanism then you should put some sleep before retry actually happens. So put some sleep in Try block.

Comment: @AmitD wouldn't a sleep just delay the problem?

Comment: @Anirudh agreed, that's why I'm asking the question. A callback would just increase the stack trace I'm afraid, no?

Comment: @RomainPiel No. Currently what happens is if OP gets error one time there is every possible chance that OP will get it several times.We don't know why ConnectionException occurs but Looking at the exception I don't think that it will be immediately cured in next go. So Imagine even if it occurs for few seconds OP will have StackOverflow error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a simple loop like his?

```
public void subscribe(final String channel) {
   while(true){
       try {
          // blocking command
          client.subscribe(channel);
          return;
       } catch(ConnectionException e) {
          // ignored
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: correct, it would work. I didn't think of that because I'm not a big fan of while(true), thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have an infite recursion.
Put a recursion breaking condition. You need to have a condition where recursion should stop. Put an if block and stop the recursion logically at some point.

Comment: I agree but I can't find any correct condition for breaking the recursion and that's what's bugging me. Looks like using recursion is just not adapted in my situation.